# How to speedup my Libsvm vector to std::vector<float> conversion?

Tags: c++, vector, libsvm, euclidean-distance

## Introduction

I have a libsvm vector of the form:

*{i_1:v_1; i_2:v_2;...; i_n:v_n}*

Where ***i_j:v_j*** represent respectively the **index** and the **value**. If the value is null then it wont be given any index.

> My objective is to compute the euclidean distance between two libsvm
>   vectors. For that I have to convert them to `vector<float>` of the same
>   size. In the following example i'll be showing the function that I used in order to convert the libsvm vector into `vector<float>`.

---

## Example

The first column has an index = *2648* and a value = *0.408734* meaning that all the values before it are zeros.

**LIBSVM VECTOR = 2648:0.408734;4157:0.609588;6087:0.593104;26747:0.331008**

---

## Source code

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;
//convert libsvm vector to float vector in order to compute the similarity
vector<float> splitVector(const vector<string> &);

int main()
{
   vector<string> libsvm {"2648:0.408734","4157:0.609588","6087:0.593104","26747:0.331008" };
   high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
   vector<float> newVec = splitVector(libsvm);
   high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
   auto duration = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>( t2 - t1 ).count();
   cout <<"construction time: " << duration << endl;
   return 0;
}

vector<float> splitVector(const vector<string> & v)
{
    int numberofterms = 266373;
    vector<float> values;
    vector<int> previous_idx;
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        vector<string> tmpv;
        boost::split(tmpv, v[i] , boost::is_any_of(":"));
        //idx:value
        int idx = atoi(tmpv[0].c_str());
        float val = atof(tmpv[1].c_str());

        //summation of previous indices
        int sum = accumulate(previous_idx.begin(), previous_idx.end(), 0);
        int n = idx - (sum + i + 1);
        //fill vector with 0s
        for(int k = 0; k < n; k++)
            values.push_back(0.0);
        //add value
        values.push_back(val);
        previous_idx.push_back(n);
    }//end for

    int paddingsize = numberofterms - values.size();

    for(int i = 0; i < paddingsize;i++)
    {
      values.push_back(0.0);
    }
    return values;
}//end function
```

---

## Problem

The timing of the conversion is around *0,00866* seconds and when I have around *1000* vectors it becomes slow.  Is there a faster way to convert the libsvm vector into `vector<float>`?

---

## Modified function

```
values.resize(266373,0.0);
void splitVector(const vector<string> & v, vector<float> & values)
{
    vector<string> tmpv;
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        boost::split(tmpv, v[i] , boost::is_any_of(":"));
        //idx:value
        int idx = atoi(tmpv[0].c_str());
        float val = atof(tmpv[1].c_str());
        tmpv.clear();
        values[idx] = val;
    }//end for

}//end function
```

Comment: `vector<float> newVec = plitVector(libsvm);` <- afaik this shouldn't even compile

Comment: sorry i copied wrong oups

Comment: `vector<int> libsvm {"2648:0.408734","4157:0.609588","6087:0.593104","26747:0.331008" };` int vector with string initialization?

Comment: Reuse `tmpv`; preallocate `values` and `previous_idx`

Comment: @timrau if I have more than one libsvm vectors the size will  be different. So for **previous_idx** i have to preallocate memory every time I enter the function. As for **values** I guess yes it  can be done because the size of the vector is  constant **266373**. Am I right?

Comment: You could still reuse `previous_idx` since `previous_idx.clear()` does not really free up the memory. It just reset the size of vector back to 0, and the previously-allocated memory could be reused until the capacity is not enough.

Comment: And if `values` is always of size 266373, then you could use `reserve(266373)` at the beginning to allocate enough memory and use `resize(266373, 0.0)` in the end instead of calling multiple times of `push_back()`.

Comment: @timrau I wrote a function where I pre allocate can you check it please? the time became 0,000109 lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reduce time cost on memory allocation by reusing `vector`s.
To be more specific,

- Reuse `tmpv` by declaring it before the `for` loop and call `tmpv.clear()` in the beginning of each loop
- Preallocate `values` by `values.reserve()`; and pad it by `values.resize(266373, 0.0)` instead of repeated `push_back()`.
- Reuse `previous_idx` if possible. This may has negative impact on the code structure and thus maintainability.